# How can I make animals unkillable?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Since I showed my 3 year old son the tree house and farm I had built in Minecraft, he has become a huge fan of the game also.  At first I would play and he would watch, but now he has started playing himself.  I've created a **creative** world for him and set the difficulty to **peaceful**.  I have built a house and a little farm with wheat, cows, chickens, pigs and sheep.  He loves playing farmer.

Unfortunately, as a farmer, he is not always being nice to his animals.  He often punches the animals when they are in the way and then the animals die.  I would like to be able to make the animals unkillable, because I don't like him killing defenseless animals.

Is there a mod or something that I can use to make the animals unkillable?  I have tried searching Google, minecraftforum.net and gaming.se, but I haven't found anything useful yet.

Comment: If there's no mod to make them unkillable, see if there's one to turn the chicken into zelda-like chickens. Kill one, and you *will* know about it as you get mobbed by masses of squaking blocky birds.

Comment: @ProSay: Didn't I just give a very nice use-case for unkillable animals? :p  I know that it is not very likely to find a mod with that feature, but related mods might be useful too.  Maybe I can get that feature included in an existing mod.

Comment: The 'use case' you gave was that you didn't like it. Killing animals is part of the game.

Comment: @fredley: Agreed. Killing animals is necessary to play the game to its fullest. I don't think "ethics" is really an issue here, since just because someone slaughters Minecraft pigs, it doesn't imply that person is going to go out and murder a bunch of people. I think we're all guilty of killing those annoying cows from time to time.

Comment: He is not playing survival, he is playing creative so his character doesn't get hungry.  He just punches blocks away and puts block all over the place.  He does understand breeding with wheat.

Comment: @Jake: The man doesnt want his toddler playing a game in a violent manner. As a parent I can totally relate. Why are you questioning his decision on the matter rather than attempting to answer his question?

Comment: Is it wise to introduce your child to a situation where there are no consequences for using violence?  Perhaps there is a more effective solution to this problem; why does he enjoy being mean to the animals (or does he enjoy it at all; could it be as simple as, "The animal was in my way, and now it isn't")?

Comment: @Phoenix It's more like "pushing when the animals are in the way".  He doesn't really want to harm them, but the animals often get in the way when he's walking in confined spaces

Comment: @tombull89 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8p6Tfgb3Kqc

Answer (score 4):

The solution I can think of is using [MCP](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_Coder_Pack%20%22MCP), which allows you to change the source code of Minecraft (including changing the animals). But if you can't do that, try using [these files](http://www.mediafire.com/?d6seznqpkaalpug).

If you have [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org), open up your minecraft.jar and paste the files inside the zip inside jar. Then delete the META-INF folder inside.

Comment: Thanks, MCP sounds good.  I should be able to make a simple mod with that.  I'll look into it further and report back.  If I can make a toddler-friendly mod, I might publish it.

Answer (score 4):

First, give your player a command block by enabling cheats (ESC->Open to LAN->Cheats=On->Start LAN World) and typing the following command:

```
/give @p minecraft:command_block
```

Make sure that you are in creative mode (You can access this with cheats by typing in /gamemode 1)

Now, before doing anything else, make a redstone clock (designs can be found online) and put the command block on the output end (the end sending power)

After that, right click the command block and copy this command with CTRL+C (Command+C for MAC) and paste it into the top line of the command block with CTRL+V (Command+V for MAC):

```
/entitydata @e[type=!Player,r=500] {AbsorptionAmount:350000000000000000000000000000000000000.0f}
```

This will make all the animals in a radius of 500 meters (blocks) unkillable. You can't even kill them with /kill @e!

Please note that this is for 1.8.0 and up, so if you have a version below that, you need to upgrade and convert your world (which Minecraft does on it's own). Also, this may cause a bit of lag, and if it doesn't work, try replacing the redstone and comparator with a different redstone clock you can find online.

Comment: Yes I can confirm that this method works. You can even just type it into the server console (if you're running your own server). Or set the Command Block to "Always active" instead of using a redstone clock. This method however also makes all monsters unkillable too.

Comment: It is still possible to kill such an entity by using `/data` or `/execute store` to set its health to 0, but of course non-technichally-inclined minecrafters won't know that.

Comment: Also, your command needs to be updated for 1.13: `/execute as @e[type=!player,distance=..500] run data merge entity @s {AbsorptionAmount:350000000000000000000000000000000000000.0f}`

Answer (score 1):

Place down a repeating command block far underground so that it is never found and broken, and set it to "Always Active". Then, run the following command:

```
/effect @p weakness 1000000 255
```

This will make it impossible to deal any damage to any animal, because the repeating command block runs the command every tick (0.05 secs). Then, to prevent the command block output from showing up on screen, run the command:

```
/gamerule commandblockoutput false
```

Once you've run those two commands, all animals should become invincible.

Comment: The animals wouldn't actually be invincible though, this just renders survival players unable to kill them.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the animals invulnerable by doing something to the effect of:

```
/execute at @e[type=cow,distance=..10] run data merge entity @e[limit=1,sort=nearest] {Invulnerable:1b}
```

This makes any nearby cow unkillable. The distance check isnt necessary, but limits it only to nearby cows rather than any in loaded chunks