# Is there a command or plug in to stop people from harming animals in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My friend in my server keeps killing my dog and I use coreprotect to bring him back, but is there any way to turn a specific users ability to do that? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make animals unkillable?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47239/how-can-i-make-animals-unkillable)

Answer (score 1):

There is no advanced permissions system in Vanilla Minecraft.

The best you can do on the player side is to give the player Weakness with a level of 4 or higher:

```
/effect give <name> weakness 2 3
```

But that way someone with a Sharpness 5 diamond axe and Strength 2 can deal 1½ hearts of damage with a critical hit. So you should probably modify the dog instead. This command makes the nearest dog or wolf invincible:

```
/data merge entity @e[type=wolf,sort=nearest,limit=1] {Invulnerable:1}
```